# Syntax must be formatted as a list of one-liners

Tags: bug, documentation, documentation-editor, documentation-proposals

I'm trying to add the syntax for [`git pull` documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/git/1308/pulling#t=201607220312134232407)

But I can't submit to review because I'm getting this error:

[image]

I'm pretty sure I have it formatted correctly:

[image]

I also tried multiple list items, but same message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried removing all the excess space at the front so it doesn't try to get formatted as a code block inside a list?

Comment: @animuson yes, same error message. also note that because of the `<` symbols it's rendered as an html tag and is invisible.

Comment: Tried manually escaping the `<` and `>` characters? If it's removing them as invalid HTML then it might be freaking out about that. Not sure why those aren't automatically encoded as I don't believe *any* actual HTML is valid there? Don't quote me on that.

Comment: @animuson yup - that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like the problem is the code formatting. Use inline code instead:

```
- `git pull [options [<repository> [<refspec>...]]`
```

Comment: I tried many newlines before and after. I also tried 3 spaces at the beginning, same error - if I do 4 it's no longer a list item. I tried at least 100 spaces after the line - still same error message.

Comment: Got it to go through finally - see edit.

Comment: ya, thanks! animuson pointed me that way :)

Comment: or `&lt;` / `&gt;` ?

Comment: Yeah, that should also work, @Macro.