# Documentation bug: Can't use less-than, greater-than signs in syntax block

Tags: bug, documentation

When I try to write something with those characters like `<Type>` while editing the syntax section the wrong error shows up (`Syntax must be formatted as a list of one-liners`), and I can't publish my changes.

Work-around: Use `&lt;` `&gt;`.

[image: Error]

Comment: Try sourrounding with backicks

Comment: This get past the error but the styling of the text is not aligned with the rest... The syntax block has already its specific "code style" css styling, you should not use an additional code block. It's a bug.

Comment: Also, thanks to the one who downvoted, bug reports are not like other meta discussions, please read them before pressing the down arrow...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328834